# update data in the junction table

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, linq, asp.net-core

ASP.Net Core vs MySQL

Student table and Course table are joined with the junction table StudentCourse:

```
Student      StudentCourse       Course
=========    ============        =======
PK | ID      FK | StudentID       PK | ID
   | Name    FK | CourseID           | Name
```

A student changes his course so manager needs to change CourseID in the junction table StudentCourse.

But I don't have direct access to the junction table due to:

```
public class AppDbContext
{
    public DbSet<CourseModel> CourseModels { get; set; }
    public DbSet<StudentModel> StudentModels { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<StudentCourse>()
            .HasKey(t => new { t.StudentId, t.CourseId });

        builder.Entity<StudentCourse>()
            .HasOne(sc => sc.Student)
            .WithMany(s => s.StudentCourse)
            .HasForeignKey(sc => sc.StudentId);

        builder.Entity<StudentCourse>()
            .HasOne(sc => sc.Course)
            .WithMany(s => s.StudentCourse)
            .HasForeignKey(sc => sc.CourseId);
    }
}
```

So I can't execute this SQL command directly:

```
UPDATE StudentCourse SET CourseId = '9A414E30-DA37-48ED-105E-08D8129A967A' WHERE StudentId = 'A1F38C12-AE65-464C-C489-08D814F4CDDC'
```

I think I have to use Inner Join. My logic is:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult ChangeCourse(Guid id)
    {
        IQueryable<CourseModel> courses = courseModel.GetCourses();
        ViewBag.Courses = new SelectList(courses, "Id", "Name");

        var course = courseModel.GetCourseById(id);

        return View(course);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult ChangeCourse(CourseModel newCourse)
    {
        // I know student's id, so I can get his old course id
        Guid oldCourseId = (from ... in ...).SingleOrDefault();
        // Then just change and save
        oldCourseId = newCourse.Id;
        context.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction();
    }
```

I have the SQL command to get an old course id:

```
SELECT CourseId FROM StudentModels L
INNER JOIN StudentCourse R
ON L.Id = R.StudentId
WHERE L.Id = 'A1F38C12-AE65-464C-C489-08D814F4CDDC'
```

So the questions are:

1. Are my assumptions correct?
2. How to write this SQL command in LINQ?

I tried this but got the list of Ids:

```
from student in context.StudentModels join cours in context.CourseModels on student.Id equals studentId select cours.Id
```

I'm not good at LINQ, yet. Please help.

Comment: *A student changes his course so manager needs to change CourseID in the junction table StudentCourse.* Think about another solution - add a column into `StudentCourse` which defines does the current record is actual or obsolete. This can be, for example, boolean (tinyint) `Validity` column which's value of 1 or 0 means that the row is actual or obsolete. Then simply use the condition by this additional column. And you do not need in update, you must add new row when student selects new course, and mark a row as non-valid when the student ejects a course.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Hope I got what you mean. Because our school has a lot of students I afraid the table will be huge in this case. For example student Kate is visiting course A and course B. So we have two rows. Then she finished course A and goes to course C. I think it's better just modify data in the junction table: change A to C. Otherwise course A still will be in the table. We're not going to use this information (previous courses).

Comment: *Because our school has a lot of students I afraid the table will be huge in this case.* The term "huge" in MySQL starts somewhere from 10kk rows approximately. I doubt that you'll reach it. The profit of storing the full history looks more helpful. *We're not going to use this information (previous courses).* This is the current case. You have not thinking about any analytics yet - but 99% this task will appear in future.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a many-to-many relation between Students and Courses. Every Student follows zero or more Courses, and every Course is followed by zero or more Students. That why you need a junction table

You wrote:

> A student changes his course

Well, as Students can follow several Courses, you cannot say that a Student changes **his** course. You can say that a Student follows a new Course, and/or stops following another Course.

If you have followed the entity framework conventions, you will have classes similar to the following:

```
class Student
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ...

    // Every Student follows zero or more Courses (many-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses {get; set;}
}

class Course
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ...

    // Every Course is followed by zero or more Courses (many-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students {get; set;}
}
```

This is all entity framework needs to know to detect your many-to-many relationship. It will automatically create a junction table for you and use it whenever needed.

If you want to change any item in entity framework, you'll have to fetch the complete item, and use `Include` for related Collections

To Stop following a course and start following a new Course:

```
int studentId = ...
int courseIdToStop = ...
int courseIdToAttend = ...

// get the student to change; include his courses
Student studentToChange = dbContext.Students
    .Include(student => student.Courses)
    .Where(student => student.Id == studentId)
    .FirstOrDefault();


// Stop the course
Course courseToStop = studentToChange.Courses
    .Where(course => course.Id == courseIdToStop)
    .FirstOrDefault();

if (courseToStop != null)
{
    // This Student follows this cours; stop it:
    studentToChange.Courses.Remove(courseToStop);
}

Course courseToStart = dbContext.Courses
    .Where(course => course.Id == courseIdToStart)
    .FirstOrDefault();

// only start the course if course exists and not already following
if (courseToStart != null && !studentToChange.Courses.Contains(courseToStart))
{
    studentToChange.Courses.Add(courseToStart);
}

dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
**why you need a junction table**
**This is all entity framework needs to know to detect your many-to-many relationship. It will automatically create a junction table for you and use it whenever needed.**
As I know EF Core can't create a junction table automatically. Am I right?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the limitations of the core version. I only use the full entity framework. Why not test this in a small project with Schools, Teachers and Students. Give them an Address, and in about half an hour you've tested all relations: one-to-many, many-to-many, one-to-one. This is also a neat project to test future ideas, or to explain how to do relations to colleagues